# Yocto do_package_qa hangs for bin_package nodejs recipe

Tags: node.js, yocto

Using Yocto morty, I'm trying to add a prebuilt version of nodejs in my distribution.  When I bitbake core-image-sato, do_package_qa hangs for hours. I'd be grateful for your help in getting me past this issue.

I've added this to the bottom of local.conf:

```
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "mynode"
```

This is my recipe for mynode:

```
SUMMARY = "puts the node.js binary distribution into my image"
SECTION = "base"
LICENSE = "MIT & BSD & Artistic-2.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://usr/node-v7.10.0-linux-x64/LICENSE;md5=d29463feca32ea5977af7b6c7d62c14a"
SRC_URI = "https://nodejs.org/dist/v7.10.0/node-v7.10.0-linux-x64.tar.xz;subdir=usr"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "b9122f212e0716d199d7e954ff81e1ec"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "6166b9f3fb1a9e861335d864688fee5366f040db808080856a1a2b71b6019786"
S = "${WORKDIR}"
inherit bin_package
```

This is the content of log.do_install for my nodejs package.  Maybe the message from tar describes my problem somehow?

```
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_install
tar: ./pseudo/pseudo.socket: socket ignored
DEBUG: Shell function do_install finished
```

There doesn't appear to be anything useful in log.do_package_qa for my nodejs package, but maybe somebody will see something that I don't see:

```
DEBUG: Executing python function sstate_task_prefunc
DEBUG: Python function sstate_task_prefunc finished
DEBUG: Executing python function do_package_qa
NOTE: DO PACKAGE QA
DEBUG: Executing python function read_subpackage_metadata
DEBUG: Python function read_subpackage_metadata finished
NOTE: Checking Package: mynode-dev
NOTE: Checking Package: mynode
```

I see a few bitbake-worker processes running, one with argument decafbad, two with argument decafbadbeef.  I also see a pseudo process running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use

```
subdir=usr
```

At the end of `SRC_URI` then you also need to change the source directory it uses (`S`) accordingly:

```
S = "${WORKDIR}/usr"
```

In addition, I think for all pre-built binary packages (`inherit bin_package`), you want to do it that way. I tried without either and it hung forever. Also, you may want to use a `subdir` name that nothing else uses, like say `external_binary`. That way each binary recipe can use the same `subdir`.